# Trying a into statement error

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship, in-clause

Trying to do a simple insert into statement but getting an foreign key relationship error.

```
insert into orders (userId, orderDate, shippingDate)
values('xyz123', now(), now());
```

The error I am getting is 
"Cannot add or update a child row:a foreign key constraint fails ('example_1010`.`orders`,CONSTRAINT`orders_ibfk1`FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES`users`(`userid`))"

I think I need to use an "in clause" to bypass the constraint but I don't think I am using it correctly.

```
insert into orders (userId, orderDate, shippingDate)
values('xyz123', now(), now())
in (select userId from users);
```

Comment: As the error clearly states, you cannot insert `userId`s that do not exist in the users table.

Comment: try to insert same userId already exist in the users table.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the foreign key

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

you don't need any other thing to add. your query is perfect

```
insert into orders (userId, orderDate, shippingDate)
values('xyz123', now(), now());
```

after that again enable foreign key

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

You should add that user_id in your parent table(users) as suggested by @drew

Comment: so insert junk basically?

Comment: this case happens many time in a life of dba. we have to do this type of correction sometime

Comment: Fix the data where it belongs (the parent) first. Then fix the child. Otherwise you screw up your referential integrity and shouldn't even have it.